# django rest framework changing id to url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose, I have a model `Collection` and one-to-many relationship to `CollectionImage`

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CollectionImage(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection', related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(height_field='height_field', width_field='width_field')
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.collection.name
```

I created a Serializer class for my model

```
class CollectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'publish',
            'author',
            'images',
        ]
```

and a API View

```
class CollectionList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer
```

The problem that i have, is that the field images gives an array of ids, where i would like it to be an array of Image urls, is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, DRF is extremely flexible and can support this. I would suggest using a SerializerMethodField for this capability. It essentially allows you to map a serializer field to the result of a custom function.

Your implementation would look like this:

```
class CollectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'publish',
            'author',
            'images',
        ]

    def get_images(self, obj):
        return [collection_image.image.url for collection_image in obj.images]
```

Source:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

** the field is mapped to the method via the "get_" naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Can set `depth=1` to unfold all related models one level deep:

```
class CollectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'publish',
            'author',
            'images',
        ]
        depth = 1
```